# Apache Dynamic virtual host with CURL BEFORE a 301 redirect

Tags: curl, macros, apache2, virtualhost

sorry for my bad english, im italian.
I am creating a 301 virtual host in apache2 with macro for redirecting old websites fqdn to new ones.
e.g. all pages of www.old.com goes to www.new.com
so 
www.old.com/en/news/mynews.php goes to www.new.com/en/news/mynews.php

this is my vhost that works **perfectlly**

```
    <Macro vhost301 $fqdn $alias $toUrl>
    <VirtualHost 85.159.210.48:80>
            ServerAdmin info@3bit.it
            ServerName $fqdn
            ServerAlias $alias
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$alias$ [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$fqdn$ [NC]
            RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://$fqdn/$1 [R=301,L]
            Redirect permanent / http://$toUrl/
    </VirtualHost>
    </Macro>
```

**BUT** i want to do **much much more**

i would like that **BEFORE** the redirect is made, my server make a CURL to the new fqdn url and, if its response header is 200 OK (by a **CURL REQUEST**) then redirects can be done from
www.old.com/en/news/mynews.php to www.new.com/en/news/mynews.php ( cause  www.new.com/en/news/mynews.php exists and gives 200 OK )

**OTHERWISE**

if  www.new.com/en/news/mynews.php does not exists and returns not 200 OK then

www.old.com/en/news/mynews.php must go to the root www.new.com

The problem is that i cant use bash script inside virtualhosts conf file so i do not have any idea how to do so.
Any help?

Thanks in advice.

---

Sharon

Comment: you could have an error handler on your new site which in case of a 404 handles this.and then the php script can be used to do the heavy lifting

Comment: Thank you Josste for the quick answer. My server is multi sites (hundreds), therefore i can't do any manual jobs in my new and old sites. I would like to find a centralized solution.

Comment: well then the other method is instead of handling redirects in the conf file, to redirect all requests to a php file, which again does the bulk of the work - on the old server

Comment: i cant cause all my sites are chrooted via php-fpm